# Send and Receive complex datas via ksoap2 in android [Error in Serialize]

Tags: android, xmlserializer, ksoap2, serializable, ksoap

Well, I have a server that have a method

- receives a MonitorRequest (Serializable Object)
- returns a MonitorResponse[] (Serializable Object)
- Each MonitorResponse contains a MonitorDetail, that has the info I need.

code:

```
class MonitorDetail implements Serializable{
    String name;
    //Long, Short, String (...)
}

class MonitorResponse implements Serializable{
    Short returnCode;
    MonitorDetail monitorCodeList; //the request can request more than 1 monitor info.
    String user;
}

class MonitorRequest implements Serializable {
    Integer storeCode;
    Short categoryCode;
    Long[] monitorCodeList; //here I post the code of the monitors I need
    String user;
    //getters and setters
}
```

So, here is my question:
I CAN'T change the definition of those objects in the server, so how can I
make this communication without getting 'cant serialize error'.

How can I send a ProductRequest,receive a ProductResponse[] and 
obtain an specific ProductDetail via KSOAP2?

I've tried:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, OPERATION);
request.addProperty(PROPERTY, getProductConfiguredMonitorRequest());

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
enter code here
try {
    httpTransport.call("", envelope);
    SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
    return extractMonitorDetailFromResult(result);
} catch (Exception e) {
    /* a lot of stuff */
    return null;
}
return null;
```

so, how can I make this communication?

Answer (score 0):

You getResponse on envelope instead of bodyIn and then parse the SoapObject you get in a loop.

See more at

http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks